# Go I want to make a 2d array of a struct, but I am getting an error

Tags: go

Here is my code:

```
type Square struct {
    num int //Holds the number. 0 is empty
}

func somefunc() {
    squares := [4][4]Square
```

But I get this error:

```
type [4][4]Square is not an expression
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `squares := [4][4]Square{}` to complete the composite literal, or use `var squares [4][4]Square` to declare the variable.

Answer (score 0):

2d array and initialization:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Square struct {
    num int //Holds the number. 0 is empty
}

func main() {
    squares0 := [4][4]Square{} // init to zeros
    fmt.Println(squares0)

    var squares [4][4]Square // init to zeros
    fmt.Println(squares)

    squares2 := [4][4]Square{{}, {}, {}, {}} // init to zeros
    fmt.Println(squares2)

    squares3 := [4][4]Square{
        {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}},
        {{5}, {6}, {7}, {8}},
        {{9}, {10}, {11}, {12}},
        {{13}, {14}, {15}, {16}}}
    fmt.Println(squares3)

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < 4; j++ {
            squares[i][j].num = (i+1)*10 + j + 1
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(squares)
}
```

output:

```
[[{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}]]
[[{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}]]
[[{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}] [{0} {0} {0} {0}]]
[[{1} {2} {3} {4}] [{5} {6} {7} {8}] [{9} {10} {11} {12}] [{13} {14} {15} {16}]]
[[{11} {12} {13} {14}] [{21} {22} {23} {24}] [{31} {32} {33} {34}] [{41} {42} {43} {44}]]
```